# Logstash Filter output in different files according to incomming IP address

Tags: elasticsearch, input, output, logstash, elastic-stack

I am using the last version of Logstash 8.5.1.
I am trying to output log in files according to the source IP in the logstash input.

I DO know the incomming IPs. I am trying to filter them out in the filter part of the logstash pipeline configuration file.

This is what i've been trying and it always goes to my else condition no matter what I change.

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5555
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/logstash/certs/logstashcert.pem"
    ssl_key => "/etc/logstash/certs/logstashkey.pem"
    ssl_verify_mode => none
  }
}

filter {

  if "192.168.1.155" in [ip] or "192.168.1.170" in [ip] { mutate { add_field => { "logtarget" => "test" } }
  }
  if "192.168.1.160" in [ip] or "192.168.1.175" in [ip] { mutate { add_field => { "logtarget" => "prod" } }
  }
  else {
   mutate { add_field => { "logtarget" => "generic" } }
  }

}

output {

  if "test" in [logtarget] {
   file {
    path => "/opt/logstash/log/windows/test-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}.log"
   }
  }

  if "prod" in [logtarget] {
   file {
    path => "/opt/logstash/log/windows/prod-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}.log"
   }
  }

  else {
   file {
    path => "/opt/logstash/log/windows/else.log"
   }
  }

}
```

My `if` statement in filter is clearly not working because very log goes thourgh the `else` statement and are "tagged" as `generic` therefore my output conditions fails and always goes in the `else` statement which is not what I want.

The log I am trying to parse are windows logs and this is the field in the incomming data log :

```
"ip":["fe80::e50c:bb26:f198:8d6d","192.168.1.155"]
```

Does anyone has a answer for this ? Or maybe a better solution to this problematic ?

This is the ressouce i've been using so far with no luck:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/field-references-deepdive.html

Answer (score 0):

both at your filter and at output you should nest your if statements. For your output:

```
if "test" in [logtarget] {
  ....
}
else {
    if "prod" in [logtarget] {
       ....
    else
       ...
    }
}
```